# How to become Super User in a guest-session?

Tags: root, vmware, tools

I am trying to update the vmware tools. When I do it from my account it runs perfectly but when i restart the system i get the same message to update my vmware tools. The message states that i should login in the guest account and do the update. However, in order to get it done i need to become root? Any ideas?

Comment: What does the message say, exactly?

Comment: Do you get this message on the host PC or the client within the VM?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.
When I power on my system i get the following message: "Mount the virtual CD drive in the guest, launch a Terminal, and use tar to uncompress the installer. Then, execute vmware-install.pl to install VMware Tools."

Comment: When I execute the vmware-install.pl i get the following message (i am logged in the guest session) "guest-p7zum3@ubuntu:~/Desktop/vmware-tools-distrib$ ./vmware-install.pl 
Please re-run this program as the super user.

Execution aborted.

Found VMware Tools CDROM mounted at /media/guest-p7zum3/VMware Tools. Ejecting 
device /dev/sr0 ...
guest-p7zum3@ubuntu:~/Desktop/vmware-tools-distrib$ "

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Using `sudo` was one of the things that Guest sessions cannot do, by design.

Comment: But it states that the procedure has to be done in the guest session.

Comment: When I do it from my account, the next time i power my system there is a notification that VMware Tools should be updated.